# 404 Using Cron Jobs on App Engine

Tags: python-2.7, cron, yaml, google-app-engine-python, app.yaml

So I am getting this [image: error] when I try to deploy my app. Here are the files that make up my app:

main.py:

```
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write("<h1>Duracron!</h1>")

class EventHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write("<h1>Duracsron!</h1>")


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/event/.*', EventHandler),
    ], debug=True)
```

app.yaml:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

cron.yaml:

```
cron:
- description: test task
  url: /events/test
  schedule: every 1 minutes
```

I can't seem to find out what's going wrong. From my understanding, the `cron.yaml` will make a request to the `/events/test` and `app.yaml` will redirect it to `main.app` and `main.app` routes it to `EventsHandler()`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a typo in the word `event` which doesn't match `events` and that may be the cause of the problem. Try changing `('/event/.*', EventHandler),` to `('/events/.*', EventHandler),` so that it matches your `cron.yaml`